# Questions about a graph with a single perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with a single perfect matching $M$.

1. Show that $G$ has no alternating cycle,
2. Proof that if $G$ is bipartite then $X$ and $Y$ contain a 1-degree vertex.

---

I know that if $G$ has an alternating cycle $C$ then I would be able to define another perfect matching $M - M\cap E(C) + E(C \backslash M)$. So, there is no cycle in $G$.

Since $G$ has no (odd) cycle, then it is a tree. If it is a tree then $G$ contains at least two leafs. Let $v, u \in V(G)$ be leafs. We can consider that $v \in X$, for bipartitins $X$ and $Y$ of $G$.

I'm not sure how to continue to show that $u \in Y$. Can I argue that, since $M$ is a perfect matching, then there is a alternating path from $v$ to $u$ that must be even, and because of that $u \in Y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful: just because $G$ has no alternating cycle doesn't mean it has no cycle, so it is not necessarily a tree. Consider the following graph:

[image: non-alternating cycle]

Here, there is a unique perfect matching (the degree-$1$ vertices force it), but the red edges form a cycle - just not an alternating cycle.

Fortunately, you don't need to know that the graph is a tree. Just take an alternating path of maximal length, and look at its endpoints $u$ and $v$.

First of all, both $u$ and $v$ must have degree $1$. (Otherwise, either you could extend the alternating path, or turn it into an alternating cycle.)

Second, because a perfect matching exists, the single edge out of $u$, and the single edge out of $v$, must both be part of the perfect matching. Therefore $u$ and $v$ are on opposite sides of the bipartition by looking at their parity along the alternating path.

Comment: For purposes of "how would you come up with this?" intuition, you can think of this argument as a generalization of the "if a graph has minimum degree 2, then it has a cycle" argument.

Comment: If both $u$ and $v$ are 1-degree vertexes, then the edges inciding on them must be in the perfect matching. Thus, can I state that this path I have from $u$ to $v$ have odd length greater or equal to 3 and, because of that, each vertex must lie in different partitions?

Comment: Well, it can have odd length 1: you could have $u$ and $v$ be the two endpoints of an edge in the perfect matching. Otherwise, yes.